# I am trying to store image path in mysql database through spring framework...but not able to do it..:/

Tags: java, mysql, spring, image, upload

```html
<h3>File to upload</h3>

<form action ="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type ="file" name ="file">
<input type ="submit" value ="submit">
</form>
```

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView upload(@RequestParam("file") CommonsMultipartFile file,HttpSession session) throws IOException
{
    String path =  session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    String filename=file.getOriginalFilename();
    ImagePOJO pojo = new ImagePOJO();
    byte barr[]=file.getBytes();    


    pojo.setPath(path);
    pojo.setFilename(filename);

    //String q = pojo.setPath(path)+"/"+pojo.setFilename(filename); 

    String w = pojo.getPath()+""+pojo.getFilename();
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(barr));


    System.out.println(path+" "+filename);

    System.out.println(w);


    BufferedOutputStream bout;
    try {
        bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+filename));


        Object o = bout;
        bout.write(barr);
        bout.flush();
        bout.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) a go?

Generate yourself a spring boot application at http://start.spring.io/.

Add these dependencies to your pom.

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Add an `UploadStore` to your main class:

> SpringBootApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringContentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringContentApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StoreRestResource(path="upload")
    public interface UploadStore extends Store<String> {
    }
}
```

Each uploaded file needs a unique name so let's generate a guid and dynamically set the form's action.  Update the html like this:

> form.html

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.myform.action = get_action();
    }

    function get_action() {
        return "upload/" + guidGenerator();
    }

    function guidGenerator() {
        var S4 = function() {
           return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
        };
        return (S4()+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+S4()+S4());
    }
</script>

<html>
    <body>
        <h3>File to upload</h3>

        <form name=myform method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type ="file" name ="file">
            <input type ="submit" value ="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Run your application and give the UploadStore a location:

```
java -jar yourapp.jar --spring.content.fs.filesystemRoot=/path/to/your/store
```

`UploadStore` and `upload` are not great names as this is a fully function content service that supports POST, PUT, GET and DELETE.  GET even supports video streaming.

UploadStore can also be made to implement `Renderable` to enable getting renditions of your uploaded content; i.e. GET a PDF of an uploaded word document for example.

And/Or `Searchable` to enable fulltext indexing (but this also requires Apache Solr).

And it can be combined with Spring Data allowing you to associate Spring Data Entities and Spring Content Resources.

HTH